# Is it possible to change defaultSessionConfiguration of NSURLSessionConfiguration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, nsurlsession

I have an ios app. I want to modify `defaultSessionConfiguration` so that every time later in the code when I call `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]` I will get my modified `defaultSessionConfiguration`

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
// Set the proxy configuration options in the connectionProxyDictionary property
NSDictionary *proxyDict = @{
    @"HTTPSEnable": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    @"HTTPSProxy": @"localhost",
    @"HTTPSPort": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1234]
};
configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;
```

This one gives me a configuration with an empty connectionProxyDictionary

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration2 = [NSURLSessionConfiguration  defaultSessionConfiguration];
```

There is a lib in my app that makes requests to some host. I know that this lib uses `NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration`. I want to modify the "global"  `defaultSessionConfiguration` so that the lib would start sending requests through my proxy.

Comment: The documentation for `defaultSessionConfiguration` states: *"Modifying the returned session configuration object does not affect any configuration objects returned by future calls to this method, and does not change the default behavior for existing sessions. It is therefore always safe to use the returned object as a starting point for additional customization."*.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can really do would be to swizzle the method (and I can't be 100% certain that you won't run into class cluster weirdness that might prevent doing that).

At a high level, you'd do something like this:

- Create a method implementation (`IMP`) using `imp_implementationWithBlock`.  IIRC, its parameters should be:

  - The object that is being operated on
  - The method parameters in order
- Look up the method with `class_getInstanceMethod`.
- Replace the implementation of that method using `method_setImplementation`.
- Store the result of that method (the previous `IMP`) in a static global variable.
- Cast the IMP to a function pointer.  IIRC, the arguments the function pointer should be:

  - The object that is being operated on
  - The selector for the method (`@selector(defaultSessionConfiguration)`)
  - The method parameters in order
- Call that function pointer from the custom implementation block, then modify the results before returning them.

Be sure to do all of this in a dispatch_once block, e.g.

```
- (void)load {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static id sharedInstance;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    // Code goes here...
  });
}
```

to ensure that you cannot do this more than once.

Note, however, that this is fairly risky to do in a production app.  It is better, whenever possible, to ask the framework developer to provide hooks for passing in a session of your own creation (or a configuration of your own creation).

Documentation links:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418587-imp_implementationwithblock?language=objc
- https://petersteinberger.com/blog/2014/a-story-about-swizzling-the-right-way-and-touch-forwarding/